# MVC retrieve value dynamically from resource file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to retrieve value dynamically from resource file.

Resource file looks like:

pagecontent
n1 - "John" 
n2 - "Mike"
n3 - "Dan"

I want to loop though viewmodel passed to the view and grab the value from item.Name.

i.e item.Name value = n1 then grab the text from resource file and display n1's value which is John.

```
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <h1> @Resources.pagecontent.[??]/h1>
       }
```

Is it possible to do that dynamically?

Viewmodel

```
public class CompanyNamesVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    ....
}
```

if I loop it. Result would shown 
n1 
n2 
n3 
...

Comment: please show your view model

Comment: @rogerdeuce updated.

Comment: So your view model doesn't actually have the names included in it?

Comment: That is correct. It only have codes for the names. I put in the resource file because some names are in French letters, so if page needs to be rendered into french, data will come from fr resource file. @rogerdeuce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by doing this:

```
 @Resources.pagecontent.ResourceManager.GetString(item.Name)
```